# Is there a limit for TClientDataSet filter, or is it a bug?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap, tclientdataset

I'm using a `TClientDataSet` as an in-memory table and must apply a filter with a lot of conditions.

For example, with 400 `OR` conditions, I get an access violation when I try to enable the filter.

> Access violation at address 4DAEDC76 in module 'midas.dll'. Read of address 00000034.

The exception occurs here :

```
procedure TCustomClientDataSet.AddExprFilter(const Expr: Widestring; Options: TFilterOptions); 
begin 
  if FExprFilter <> nil then FDSCursor.DropFilter(FExprFilter); 
  if Expr <> '' then 
  with TExprParser.Create(Self, Expr, Options, [poExtSyntax], '', nil, FieldTypeMap, True) do 
    try 
      CheckProviderEOF; 
      Check(FDSCursor.AddFilter(FilterData, DataSize, FExprFilter)); // ** AV HERE
    finally 
      Free; 
    end; 
end;
```

Is it a bug on component or it's a limitation of the midas.dll ?
I tested this behavior on these midas's versions: >= 15 and <= 23

I'm using Delphi XE.
Example code:

```
procedure TForm41.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  FilterStr: string;
begin
  FilterStr := '(vehicleId = -1)';
  //It is just an example, the original code I can have any integer number.
  for I := 0 to 400 do //If I change the limit value to 40 for example, it works. 
    FilterStr := FilterStr + ' or (vehicleId = ' + IntToStr(I) + ')';

  ClientDataSet1.Filter := FilterStr;
  ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet; //Error here
end;
```

I already tried to use IN statement, but I get the same error.

I didn't found references about this situation on internet.

Comment: What exception do you get? Why would you possibly need to add 400 OR conditions? If you're having to do that, you're doing something terribly wrong. If you need to filter that much, do it in the main dataset or by using the `TClientDataSet.OnFilterRecord` event.

Comment: Legacy code Ken White, nothing that I can change easily with out a lot of modifications. It's a permission filter, the user can see 400 vehicles.

Comment: You can use the `OnFilterRecord` without major modifications. You still haven't indicated what exception you're getting. What **exact** exception message are you seeing?

Comment: I general access violation, I tracked the code: 
It happens on this line:
Check(FDSCursor.AddFilter(FilterData, DataSize, FExprFilter));

that is on:
procedure TCustomClientDataSet.AddExprFilter(const Expr: Widestring; Options: TFilterOptions);
begin
  if FExprFilter <> nil then FDSCursor.DropFilter(FExprFilter);
  if Expr <> '' then
    with TExprParser.Create(Self, Expr, Options, [poExtSyntax], '', nil, FieldTypeMap, True) do
    try
      CheckProviderEOF;
      Check(FDSCursor.AddFilter(FilterData, DataSize, FExprFilter));
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen a Delphi exception that said nothing but *General Access Violation*. For the **third  time**, what is the **exact** error message you're seeing? Not *I see something like*, but the **exact error message**, including memory addresses.

Comment: "Access violation at address 4DAEDC76 in module 'midas.dll'. Read of address 00000034."

Comment: That address indicates you're reading an object pointer that hasn't been created. Please post your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106384/discussion-between-rodrigo-farias-rezino-and-ken-white).

Comment: Fix your filter. Your code example can be simplified to `(vehicleId >= -1) and (vehicleID <= 400)`, which does not suffer from any issues. If you can't do that, use the `OnFilterRecord` event handler and filter each record.

Comment: It is just an example, the original code I can have any integer number.

Comment: For brevity, `WHERE vehicleID IN (1, 3, 7, 15, 77, 156, 204, 191, [...etc])` may be more appropriate.  Also, for any subset, you can at least limit the filter to no more than half the set size, either using `IN` or `NOT IN`.

Comment: Yes J..., I tried it too, but I get the same error.

Comment: Which version of Delphi, out of curiosity?

Comment: As an aside, older versions of Midas also have an issue with LIKE expressions with no wildcards see http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=101123. Adding here as symptoms are similar

Comment: which version of midas.dll do you use? sample produced with d2007 and v.14.0.3593.25826 doesn't exhibit AV

Comment: It's interesting vavan, I tested here with version  >= 15  and <= 23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this error, including the "Read of address 00000034" in Delphi Seattle.
It occurs when more than about 280 terms are in the Filter expression.  It's
obviously a midas limitation.  You need a better way of translating from your problem domain
to the desired effect of your filter.

If you can evaluate your condition in code, then what I would do is to add
a boolean fkInternalCalc field to the CDS and set it to True of False
depending on the result. Then, filtering the dataset is a simple matter
of applying a filter based on the value of the boolean.

Comment: Thanks MartynA. Where did you found the valeu 280 ? Do you know any in memory table ?  thanks

Comment: By experiment: noting that I got the exception with 300 terms, but not 200,  I did a binary search in between.  There are numerous other in-memory tables, but I always use a CDS for this kind of stuff, despite its occasional shortcomings.

Comment: I found others in-memory table, but all of them are based on TDataSet. There are others that I found but I didn't know it's implementation 'cause they are not free.

Comment: Not strictly an in-memory db, but have you tried Sqlite?  More recent Delphi versions have pretty good support for it via FireDAC, but you might find there's support for it in DBExpress in XE.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino While it's only a temporary (and still inelegant) solution, you can always reduce the number of filter elements, for a set of 400, to a maximum of 200 by using inclusive filters (ie: include the selected IDs) for fewer than 200 items and exclusive filters (ie: exclude the non-selected IDs) for more than 200 items.

Comment: Thank you J... and MartynA for you collaboration. I'll try to get a definitive solution, I found two free option: kbmMemTable and SqlMemTable (http://www.aidaim.com/products/sent.php). I'll check those capacity.